# "Permission denied" error

Tags: command-line, permissions, 12.10

Alright so I installed Ubuntu last night and I am very new to everything.

Right now I am trying to run a program called JES, (Jython Environment for Students). The instructions tell me to cd to the JES directory I have, so I type

```
cd /home/Programs/JES
```

It takes me to the directory I need to be in, so far so good. Then I have to type in:

```
./JES.sh
```

And I get this returned to me:

```
bash: ./JES.sh: Permission denied
```

I have very little comprehension of what to do in Terminal or anything of the sort. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried using

```
sudo -l
```

to get permissions but it still persists.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the file does not have permission to execute it:

```
chmod +x JES.sh
```